# Spring-boot-starter dependecy in common lib

Tags: spring-boot

In a multi module  project

- X

  - common
  - app

Is there any utility to have spring-boot-starter dependecy in common instead of app?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want the `spring-boot-starter` dependency to be in a common field for all your modules?

Comment: I have one module used by others, so i was thinking to put there

Answer (score 1):

There is definite value in putting spring-boot-starter dependency in the common pom. The utility is that the spring boot version only needs to be updated in one place. Also any other dependencies can be managed in one place - for vulnerability mitigation.

*All* the (version-)managed dependencies also need to go in the common pom because putting them in app pom leaves these dependencies without versions.

I would go further and suggest all dependencies are captured in the common pom to allow better control and vulnerability mitigation.

There are some downsides to consider:

- Lots of versions of common as managed dependencies get added to apps
- Any `<scope>test</scope>` will have to come out because the dependency jar needs to get into the common.jar
- Good discipline in the team to ensure common dependencies are added to common pom.

These are sample poms and a snippet of app code to help explain:

**common pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>common</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- version managed by spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- version managed by spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- version not managed by spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**app pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>app</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- to pick up the spring-boot-starter-parent and other common dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- a specific dependency only used in app -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.basc.start</groupId>
        <artifactId>verification-code</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**A sample app class:**

```
    import org.hibernate.query.sqm.function.SelfRenderingSqmAggregateFunction;
    import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmAggregateFunction;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    
    import com.google.common.escape.Escaper;
    import com.google.common.html.HtmlEscapers;
    
    import io.basc.start.verificationcode.VerificationCodeRecipient;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class App {
    // This comes from managed org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core
    SqmAggregateFunction<String> annotationDescriptor = new SelfRenderingSqmAggregateFunction<String>(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    // This comes from unmanaged com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre
    Escaper escaper = HtmlEscapers.htmlEscaper();

    // This comes from local dependency io.basc.start:verification-code:1.8.3
    VerificationCodeRecipient verificationCodeRecipient = new VerificationCodeRecipient();
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // This comes from spring-boot-starter-parent
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, but prefert to use gradle simpler to read